# Streaming camera view on image plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, camera, image, video

I want to create animation with smartphone which will be translate view from one of cameras. Can I somehow connect phone_screen/image plane to camera view? Or will it be simpler to make another animation and somehow play it on plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found solution. it's simpler to create another animation and play it on any surface, but it can be difficult to synchronize video on phone screen and environment, if you wanna simulate phone camera effect in movement.